# What does NFP RC mean in marriage record of Virginia 1799?

Tags: marriage-records, ancestry.com, virginia, abbreviations

I found a book on Ancestry.com that transcribes:

```
EGBERT, Delency & DALE, Sally; bef. 21 Oct 1799; bride was a dau. of Jn. (& Lucy 
    ?) DALE of NFP, RC and a sis. of Reuben DALE; by Oct 1799 both Delency & 
    Sally (DALE) EGBERT and Reuben & Sally DALE were res. of Woodford Co., 
    Ky; (NC DC Ord Etc:363)
```

From this image of a section of page 124 of the book:

> [image: Image from ancestry.com]

The Ancestry.com record reads:

```
Name:   Sally Dale
Marriage Date:  Abt 1799
Spouse Name:    Delency Egbert
Marriage Location:  Virginia, United States
```

Source info:

```
Source Information
Title
Virginia, Marriages of the Northern Neck of Virginia, 1649-1800
Author
Ancestry.com
Publisher
Ancestry.com Operations, Inc.
Publisher Date
2012
Publisher Location
Provo, UT, USA
```

I am wondering what `NFP, RC` stands for?  Also what does `NC DC Ord Etc:363` refer to, I imaging page 363 of some book?

Abbreviations on pages 411–2 show:

```
DC — <no entry>
NC — Northumberland County
NFP — North Farnham Parish, Richmond Co
Ord — <no entry>
RC — Richmond County
```

Here is the table of contents for the book:

> [image]

Going to the References p. 398–9 I found:

[image]
...
[image]

Comment: If you attach an image of the record I can look at it further, but I don't have an ancestry world subscription. So I can't see the record.

Comment: I think it would add helpful context to the question. Is it just an ancestry transcription or a scan of the actual book?

Comment: Usually ancestry has an image number when viewing the record does it say anything like 363/504 etc?

Comment: Ahh, can you navigate to further pages in the collection?

Comment: In most books, there is an explanation of abbreviations at the beginning or the end.

Comment: @DannyBarber Yes, I can navigate, what page in particular are you interested in seeing?

Comment: Juat wondering if the last one has sources or anything

Comment: pp. 411–2 are abbreviations and after that is a long index of names.

Comment: @DannyBarber I added the TOC image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NFP, RC` is a place abbreviation for North Farnham Parish, Richmond County, Virginia.

`NC DC Ord Etc:363`, I believe is a source or case citation. [This is the Original Book the record came from.](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Married_Well_and_Often.html?id=euPmPAAACAAJ&redir_esc=y) It's only available as a rare book now.

```
Title   Married Well and Often: Marriages of the Northern Neck of Virginia, 1649-1800 : Marriages and Marriage References for the Counties of Lancaster, Northumberland, Old Rappahannock, Richmond, and Westmoreland
Author  Robert Kirk Headley
Publisher   Genealogical Publishing Company, 2003
ISBN    0806317329, 9780806317328
Length  504 pages
Subjects    Reference › Genealogy & Heraldry
```